# Given that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_i=m+r$, show that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2\leq{m+r^2}$

Tags: summation, contest-math

The summation of real numbers $x_i\in (0,1)\, \text{for}\, i=1,\ldots ,n$ is equal to $m+r$, where $m$ is an integer and $r\in [0,1)$.

> Show that $$\sum_{i=1} ^n x_i^2\leq m+r^2.$$

I pick up this question in Poland final round olympiad (1988). It seems trivial, but I couldn't present an accurate proof for it.

Comment: So you are essentially asked to show that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_i-x_i^2\leq{r-r^2}$, right?

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles. "A problem from contest math" does not tell possible helpers anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The squared distance from the origin for points on the compact polyhedron given by $\sum x_i=m+r$, $0\le x_i\le 1$ assumes its maximum on a vertex, i.e. when a maximal number of coordinates is either $0$ or $1$. That means that there are $m$ times $x_i=1$, one is $=r$ (note that $m<n$), and the rest is $=0$. In that situation $\sum x_i^2=m+r^2$.

Comment: More explain, please.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove this by induction. The base case is trivial, and for the inductive case we have

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \leq m_n + r_n^2$$
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} x_i^2 \leq m_n + r_n^2 + x_{n+1}^2$$

and we just need to show that $m_n + r_n^2 + x_{n+1}^2 \leq m_{n+1} + r_{n+1}^2$.

In the case where $r_n + x_{n+1}$ is less than 1, we have $m_{n+1} = m_n, r_{n+1} = r_n + x_{n+1}$, and the inequality is obviously true. Otherwise, $1 \le r_n + x_{n+1} < 2$ and $m_{n+1} = m_n + 1, r_{n+1} = r_n + x_{n+1} - 1$. So,

$$m_{n+1} + r_{n+1}^2 = m_n + 1 + (r_n + x_{n+1} - 1)^2$$ 
$$=m_n + r_n^2 + x_{n+1}^2 + 2(r_nx_{n+1} - r_n - x_{n+1} + 1)$$

and we just need to show that $rx - r - x + 1 \ge 0$, where I have dropped the subscripts for simplicity, or equivalently $r + x - rx \le 1$. This follows easily: $r + x - rx \le r + x - r \le 1$, completing the proof.